# How to pass argument in button's addtarget function?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have a button that I wrote by code.

```
func someFunc(id: Int) {
    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 32, height: 32))
}
```

I need that when I click on the button it sends id (that is written in the above function) to my function.

So, i am writing @objc func

```
@objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton) {

    passIdHere(id: Int) //here I need to write my id inspite of int
        
}
```

And adding this to my button.

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can´t do that as you plan to do. But `UIButton` has a `.tag` property of type `Int`. You can use that to pass the id on.

```
func someFunc(id: Int) {
    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 32, height: 32))
    // add the tag to the button
    button.tag = id
}
```

and then:

```
@objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton) {
    // read the id from the tag
    passIdHere(id: sender.tag ) //here I need to write my id inspite of int
    
}
```

### Edit:

Regarding your comment on using a Dictionary as parameter:

This would need a bit more coding.

```
//Create a custom class that derives from UIButton
class MyButton: UIButton{
    //Create a variable to hold your array and initialize it
    var anyTag: [Int:String] = [:]
}

func someFunc(id: Int) {
    //Create a MyButton instead of a Button
    let button = MyButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 32, height: 32))
    // add the tag to the button
    button.anyTag = [1:"test"]
}

@objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton) {
    // cast the sender to MyButton
    guard let button = sender as? MyButton else{
        return
    }
    
    // retrieve the dictionary
    let dictionary: [Int:String] = button.anyTag
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that is very easy solution.

Comment: Can you tell me if it is not Int but for example [Int: String], how can i pass the value? @burnsi

Comment: @developer please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thnaks for your help. It solved my problem fully. I really appreciate it. @burnsi